# How to apply custom fonts to whole project, Expo React Native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo

I'm new to React and those languages. Trying to apply a custom google font(Ubuntu) to whole project. I managed to pull the font into the project, but I can only use it in simple texts in App.js. Like this:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './firebase/index';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'react-native-elements';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { BLUE } from './common/colors';
import Dashboard from './screens/Dashboard';
import Login from './screens/Login';
import Accounts from './screens/Accounts';
import Cards from './screens/Cards';
import Credits from './screens/Credits';
import Insurances from './screens/Insurances';
import Investments from './screens/Investments';
import MoneyTransfers from './screens/MoneyTransfers';
import OtherOperations from './screens/OtherOperations';
import Payments from './screens/Payments';

import * as Font from "expo-font";
import Apploading from "expo-app-loading";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";


const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const getFonts = () =>
  Font.loadAsync({
    limelight: require("./assets/fonts/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf"),
    indie: require("./assets/fonts/Ubuntu-BoldItalic.ttf"),
  });


export default function App() {

  const [fontsloaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);
  if (fontsloaded){
    return (
      <View>
          <Text 
            style={{ fontFamily: "limelight" }}>
             Hello World
          </Text>
          <Text 
            style={{ fontFamily: "limelight" }}>
             Hello World
          </Text>
          <Text 
            >
             Hello World
          </Text>
          <Text 
            style={{ fontFamily: "indie" }}>
             Hello World
          </Text>
          <Text 
            style={{ fontFamily: "limelight" }}>
             Hello World
          </Text>
          <Text 
            >
             Hello World
          </Text>
          <Text 
            style={{ fontFamily: "indie" }}>
             Hello World
          </Text>
          <Text 
            style={{ fontFamily: "indie" }}>
             Hello World
          </Text>
          <Text 
            >
             Hello World
          </Text>
          <Text 
            >
             Hello World
          </Text>
          <Text 
            style={{ fontFamily: "limelight" }}>
             Hello World
          </Text>
          <Text 
            >
             Hello World
          </Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
  else {
    return (
      <Apploading
        startAsync={getFonts}
        onFinish={() => {
          setFontsLoaded(true);
        }}
        onError={console.warn}
      />
    );
  }
  
}
```

But I used those text just for test. In normal my code is like this and when I try to use ubuntuRegular font it is not working.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './firebase/index';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'react-native-elements';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { BLUE } from './common/colors';
import Dashboard from './screens/Dashboard';
import Login from './screens/Login';
import Accounts from './screens/Accounts';
import Cards from './screens/Cards';
import Credits from './screens/Credits';
import Insurances from './screens/Insurances';
import Investments from './screens/Investments';
import MoneyTransfers from './screens/MoneyTransfers';
import OtherOperations from './screens/OtherOperations';
import Payments from './screens/Payments';

import * as Font from "expo-font";
import Apploading from "expo-app-loading";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";


const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const getFonts = () =>
  Font.loadAsync({
    limelight: require("./assets/fonts/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf"),
    indie: require("./assets/fonts/Ubuntu-BoldItalic.ttf"),
  });


export default function App() {

  const [fontsloaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);
  if (fontsloaded){
    return (
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <ThemeProvider>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Drawer.Navigator
              drawerType="slide"
              initialRouteName="Login"
              screenOptions={{
                headerShown: true,
                headerStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: BLUE,
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  fontFamily: 'ubuntuRegular'
                },
              }}
            >
              {/* Dashboard a ayri header gecilebilir
              https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers#replacing-the-title-with-a-custom-component */}
              <Drawer.Screen
                name="Login"
                component={Login}
                options={{ headerShown: false, title: 'Login' }}
              />
              <Drawer.Screen
                name="Dashboard"
                component={Dashboard}
                options={{ title: 'Anasayfa' }}
              />
              <Drawer.Screen
                name="Accounts"
                component={Accounts}
                options={{ title: 'Hesaplarım' }}
              />
              <Drawer.Screen
                name="Cards"
                component={Cards}
                options={{ title: 'Kartlarım' }}
              />
              <Drawer.Screen
                name="Money Transfers"
                component={MoneyTransfers}
                options={{ title: 'Para Transferleri' }}
              />
              <Drawer.Screen
                name="Investments"
                component={Investments}
                options={{ title: 'Yatırımlar' }}
              />
              <Drawer.Screen
                name="Payments"
                component={Payments}
                options={{ title: 'Ödemeler' }}
              />
              <Drawer.Screen
                name="Credits"
                component={Credits}
                options={{ title: 'Krediler' }}
              />
              <Drawer.Screen
                name="Insurances"
                component={Insurances}
                options={{ title: 'Sigortalar' }}
              />
              <Drawer.Screen
                name="Other Operations"
                component={OtherOperations}
                options={{ title: 'Diğer İşlemler' }}
              />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
  }
  else {
    return (
      <Apploading
        startAsync={getFonts}
        onFinish={() => {
          setFontsLoaded(true);
        }}
        onError={console.warn}
      />
    );
  }
  
}
```

Also how can I use this font outside of the App.js like I have a MenuTitle component:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import Apploading from "expo-app-loading";

const getFonts = () =>
  Font.loadAsync({
    limelight: require("../assets/fonts/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf"),
    indie: require("../assets/fonts/Ubuntu-BoldItalic.ttf"),
  });

const MenuTitle = ({ text, textStyles = {} }) => {
  
  return <Text style={[styles.title, textStyles]}>{text}</Text>;
};

export default MenuTitle;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    fontFamily: 'ubuntuRegular'
  },
});
```

Also this is not working. I will be glad if you can help.

Answer (score 6):

Create a folder called `hooks` where your `App.js` is located. Then inside `hooks` folder create a file called `useFonts.js`

Inside `useFonts.js` write like this

```js
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

export default useFonts = async () =>
  await Font.loadAsync({
    limelight: require('../assets/fonts/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf'),
    indie: require('../assets/fonts/Ubuntu-BoldItalic.ttf'),
  });
```

Now in your `App.js` write like this

```js
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import useFonts from './hooks/useFonts';

export default function App() {
  const [IsReady, SetIsReady] = useState(false);

  const LoadFonts = async () => {
    await useFonts();
  };

  if (!IsReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={LoadFonts}
        onFinish={() => SetIsReady(true)}
        onError={() => {}}
      />
    );
  }

  return <View styles={styles.container}>{/* Rest of the Code Here */}</View>;
}
```

Comment: AppLoading is deprecated, and when I tried implementing this solution, I couldn't get it to work. The async function loadAsync never ran when putting it in AppLoading. Also, that's not a hook  that's just a regular function

Answer (score 4):

1. Add font resource to project folder exp assets/fonts
2. create variable fonts exp customFonts
3. Import on App.js like this

> ```
> import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
> import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
> let customFonts = {
>   'Poppins-Black': require('./assets/fonts/Poppins-Black.ttf')
> };
>
> const App = () => {
>   const [isLoaded] = useFonts(customFonts);
>   if (!isLoaded) {
>     return <AppLoading />;
>   }
>     return <RootApp />;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
          fontsLoaded: false,
      }
  }
  async loadFont(){
      await Font.loadAsync({
          'ABeeZee-Italic' : require('./assets/fonts/ABeeZee-Italic.ttf'),
          'ABeeZee-Regular' : require('./assets/fonts/ABeeZee-Regular.ttf'),
      });
      this.setState({fontsLoaded:true});
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      this.loadFont();
  }
  render(){
         if(this.state.fontsLoaded)
             return Your_Component;
         else
             return AppLoading_Component;
          }
```

add the code as shown above then you can use the font on any page like below.

```
<Text style={{fontFamily: 'ABeeZee-Regular'}}> This is ABeeZee Regular Font</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried following those steps after adding .ttf to assets/font :

- Create a configuration file react-native.config.js in the root project directory and add the code below:

  ```
   module.exports = {
       project: {
           ios: {},
           android: {},
       },
       assets: ['./App/assets/fonts'],
   };
  ```
- Link the newly added asset by running the command:

  ```
  yarn react-native link
  ```

or

```
react-native link
```

If everything is right, you can see the new font assets in android/app/src/main/assets/fonts in the case of android and changes in the Info.plist in case of iOS.

Finally, Re-run your app

After this you can put your font style in a style file and then use them in all your project:

```
bold11: {
    color: Colors.black,
    fontSize: 11,
    fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold',
},
regular14: {
    color: Colors.black,
    fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular',
    fontSize: 14,
},
```

Comment: not sure this is a solution for expo, because already I don't have separate android and iOS folders in my project.

Comment: oh sorry didn't saw it was for expo, maybe here : https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-custom-fonts/#using--fontloadasync--instead-of-the

Answer (score 1):

With Expo, you generally have two distinct ways of applying custom fonts to your project:

The first is using the @expo-google-fonts/* package. Simply install the package like so:

yarn add @expo-google-fonts/Montserrat (to install Montserrat font)

Then in your code,

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import {
    useFonts,
    Montserrat_400Regular,
    Montserrat_400Regular_Italic,
    Montserrat_900Black,
} from "@expo-google-fonts/montserrat";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";

export default function App() {
    const [loadedFonts] = useFonts({
        Regular: Montserrat_400Regular,
        Italic: Montserrat_400Regular_Italic,
        Black: Montserrat_900Black,
    });

    if (!loadedFonts) {
        return <AppLoading />;
    }

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: "Regular", fontSize: 32 }}>Hello</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Use this directory for more assistance: https://directory.vercel.app/

The useFont hook handles the `Font.loadAsync` logic as displayed in other answer(s).

The second way involves importing the fonts locally. Like so,

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";

export default function App() {
    const [loadedFonts] = useFonts({
        Regular: require("./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf"),
    });

    if (!loadedFonts) {
        return <AppLoading />;
    }

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 32, fontFamily: "Regular" }}>Hello</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

### Slight note:

If you're using the latest SDK 45, expo-app-loading is deprecated and should be replaced with expo-splash-screen. The Expo [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/) will help you there.

Answer (score 0):

### Using Font.loadAsync instead of the useFonts hook If you don't want to use the useFonts hook.

```
(for example, maybe you prefer class components), you can use Font.loadAsync directly. Under the hood, the hook uses Font.loadAsync from the expo-font library. You can use it directly if you prefer, or if you want to have more fine-grained control over when your fonts are loaded before rendering.

import React from 'react';
    import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
    import * as Font from 'expo-font';
    
    let customFonts = {
      'Inter-Black': require('./assets/fonts/Inter-Black.otf'),
      'Inter-SemiBoldItalic': 'https://rsms.me/inter/font-files/Inter-SemiBoldItalic.otf?v=3.12',
    };
    
    export default class App extends React.Component {
      state = {
        fontsLoaded: false,
      };
    
      async _loadFontsAsync() {
        await Font.loadAsync(customFonts);
        this.setState({ fontsLoaded: true });
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        this._loadFontsAsync();
      }
    
      render() {
        if (!this.state.fontsLoaded) {
          return null;
        }
    
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter-Black', fontSize: 30 }}>Inter Black</Text>
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter-SemiBoldItalic', fontSize: 30 }}>
              Inter SemiBoldItalic
            </Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>Platform Default</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

with expo you can use Google Font directly by using 'expo-google-fonts' liabrary.

**Command to install**
npx expo install expo-font @expo-google-fonts/inter

**Using Google Fonts**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useFonts, Inter_900Black } from '@expo-google-fonts/inter';

export default function App() {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Inter_900Black,
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter_900Black', fontSize: 40 }}>Inter Black</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

for more help Visit Expo Docs [Expo google fonts](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-custom-fonts/#using-a-google-font)