# Can someone please help me implement Font.loadAsync

Tags: react-native, expo

**I have used Font.loadAsync many times but for some reason, I keep getting errors while trying to use it this time.**
(code is at the pastebin, it got formatted weirdly on here)

[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/1xVFtKE9)

```
import React from "react";
```

Comment: Where are you calling Font.loadAsync in the code? I don't see it in what you posted. It helps to paste it here too, so your post doesn't depend on an external resource that might go away at some point.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69275330/13170636) help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also struggling with **Font.loadAsync** in my latest project. I decided to use the `expo-font` module instead. You can initialize this module in App.js and it will load the fonts for all of your screens.

Here is an example:

```js
import React from "react";
...

import { useFonts } from "expo-font"; //need to load fonts asynchronously

...

const App = () => {

  const [loaded] = useFonts({// function for expo-font 
    RobotoBlack: FONTS.Roboto-Black.ttf,
    RobotoBold: FONTS.Roboto-Bold.ttf,
    RobotoRegular:FONTS.RobotoRegular.ttf,
  });
  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing *require* before your fonts. May need to hunt down where your fonts are coming from in your directory.

```
const App = () => {

  const [loaded] = useFonts({// function for expo-font 
    RobotoBlack: require(*font source directory*),
    RobotoBold: require(*font source directory*),
    RobotoRegular: require(*font source directory*)
  });
  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }
```

Source:
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/font/