# How to apply google fonts to entire Expo/RN app?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to use Google Fonts with my entire expo project, but i dont want to import it to each and every component. How can I just import it once, and call it everywhere? Or better yet, can I set my imported font as a default font?

app.js

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './redux/store'

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import { useFonts, Montserrat_400Regular,} from '@expo-google-fonts/montserrat';
import { HomeScreen } from './components/HomeScreen';
import { AddItemScreen } from './components/AddItemScreen';
import { DetailedDayView } from './components/DetailedDayView';

export default function App(navigation) {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Montserrat_400Regular,
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }


  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {/* <SafeAreaProvider> */}

      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomeScreen}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="AddItemScreen"
            component={AddItemScreen}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="DetailedDayView"
            component={DetailedDayView}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>

      </NavigationContainer>
      {/* </SafeAreaProvider> */}
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: use this: import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';

Answer (score 1):

## For React Native CLI:

1. First of all, download any fonts in `.ttf` format.
2. Create a directory and name it **assets**, inside the assets directory create another directory name it **fonts**, and then move the `.ttf` file here. Your path will look like this: - `root/assets/fonts/your-font.ttf`
3. Now, in your **root** directory create a file named, `react-native.config.js`. Inside that file paste the following code:

```
module.exports = {
    assets: ['./src/assets/fonts'],
}
```

4. Run this command `npx react-native-asset`. (For the older version of React Native try this command `npx react-native link`)

There you go. You're done. Now, check this directory `root/android/app/src/main/assets/fonts` to check if the font is added or not.

Now you can use your font anywhere in the app. Like this: -

```
fontFamily: 'your-font'
```

Note: You can add multiple font-family. For adding another font-family repeat **1**, **2**, and **4**.

---

### For Expo:

For Expo follow this answer: [How to apply custom fonts to whole project, Expo React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68646545/how-to-apply-custom-fonts-to-whole-project-expo-react-native)